# What am I doing wrong with my application(Java)?

Tags: java, image, swing, import, tiles

I am attempting to make a game and I am using a tileset I found(png). I want to be able to break the image up into parts and place them in specific places in the jframe to show movment. But first how would I begin to import the image. All attempts I have had have failed and the image turns to a text file when importing. Please help solve this problem and how would I cut up and arrange the tiles?

[image: Picture Link here]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at World.Display.<init>(Display.java:15)
    at Main
```

.main(Main.java:15)

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        World.Display l = new World.Display();

    }

}



package World;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Display {

    public Display() throws IOException{
        BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("assets/tilesetbackground.png/"));
        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img);
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Another RPG Version: "+Config.Global.Version);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1024,768));
        frame.setSize(1024,768);
        JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
        lbl.setIcon(icon);
        frame.add(lbl);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove the slash after png in your path ("assets/tilesetbackground.png")

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I also tried ("assets/tilesetbackground.png"), ("/assets/tilesetbackground.png/"), ("/assets/tilesetbackground.png"), ("f://assets/tilesetbackground.png"), and ("f://assets/tilesetbackground.png/")

Comment: Where is the image located in your project? Post a tree of your source directory.

Comment: Class.getResource() starts looking in the package of the class if the path doesn't start with a `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure the correct format of the string should starts from /

I checked it locally. Please take a look to the picture

[image]